# Excel формулы - Исключить пустые строки из вариантов Combo Box

Tags: excel, формулы

Хочу еще раз уточнить, что это именно Combo Box, а не тот выпадающий список, что создается через проверку данных.

Выборка значений для вып.списка: `=Тест!$E$3:$E$56`

Нужно как-то исключить пустые строки, могут быть в начале, конце или где-то между значений.

По какой-то причине варианты вида `=СМЕЩ(Тест!$E$3;;;СЧЁТ(Тест!$E$3:$E$56))` не работают, убирая все варианты у списка.

Answer (score 1):

Уточню на всякий случай: если в диапазоне нет числовых значений, *СЧЕТ(диапазон)=0*

Для счета текстовых значений нужно использовать функцию *СЧЕТЗ*. Еще лучше *СЧЕТЕСЛИ* - она сама умеет определять рабочий диапазон и можно безболезненно указывать полный столбец:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Test!$E:$E;"*")
```

> Нужно как-то исключить пустые строки, могут быть в начале, конце или
>   где-то между значений

Только формируя новый диапазон на листе. Один из вариантов - применение формулы массива:

```
=ИНДЕКС($E$3:$E$56;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($E$3:$E$56<>"";СТРОКА($E$3:$E$56)-2);СТРОКА(A1)))
```

Формула массива вводится сочетанием трех клавиш: *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, записывается в одну ячейку и протягивается по строкам. 
Если значений меньше, чем ячеек с формулой, в нижних ячейках будет ошибка *#ЧИСЛО!*. Обойти можно:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(формула;0)
```

Формула именованного диапазона c определением текстовых значений, показанная ниже,  ноль учитывать не будет:

```
=СМЕЩ(Test!$E$3;;;СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Test!$E:$E;"*"))
```